# QListView width

Tags: qt4, qlistview

I am writing a file manager, and I display the icons via a `QListView`. I want to be able to change the grid size depending on the `QListView` size, like in Dolphin. (In dolphin changing the window size, changes the grid size). I have tried getting the `QListView::size()`, `QListView::sizeHint()`, `QListView::minimumSizeHint()` and what not but I get fixed values like `QSize( 256, 192 )` every single time.

So is there a proper way to obtain the width of a QListView?

Edit: I would like to edit my question as: Is there a way to get the width of a QListView from inside its member functions? I did try getting the size as

```
    MyListView LV = new MyListView()
    qDebug() << LV.size();
```

That gives the exact size. But this does not:

```
    void MyListView::someMemberFunction() {
        ...
        ...
        qDebug() << size();
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
```

So should I reimplement something to get this working right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reimplement showEvent ( QShowEvent * event ) or paintEvent ( QPaintEvent * event ) of QListView  and get size of widget from these functions?

Here is another way.
1. Create event-filter

```
class Event_Filter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Event_Filter(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
    void table_resize();//
protected:
    virtual bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *);//
public slots:

};

bool Event_Filter::eventFilter(QObject *pObject, QEvent *pEvent)
{
   if (!pObject)
       return false;
   if(pEvent -> type() == QEvent::Resize)
   {
       emit table_resize();
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

1. mainwindow code

   ```
   table_filter = new Event_Filter();      
   connect(table_filter,SIGNAL(table_resize()),this,SLOT(slot_table_resize()));
   installEventFilter(table_filter);
   ```
2. slot code

   ```
   void MainWindow::slot_table_resize()

   {

   //resizing table headers

     if ((items_table_w != ui -> itemsTable -> viewport() -> width()) || (ui -> itemsTable -> columnWidth(DEVTABLE_COLUMN_DEVICE) <= 0))
     ......

   }
   ```

This work fine for me.

Comment: Yes indeed. It does work. Even without the event filter it does. I realized the problem arises when calling `size()` inside a member function of `QListView`, and probably other subclasses of `QQbstractItemView`.